# text not breaking from column

Tags: php, html, css

I have some script simular to what you see below:

```
#header2 {
    align:center;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 24px;
        color:red;
    }
  #column {
    width:100%;
 }


.Lcol1 {
     float:left;
     width:16.5%;

 }




  .Lcol2 {
float:left;
     position: relative;
     width:16.5%;

 }


  .Lcol3 {
float:left;
     position: relative;
     width:16.5%;

 }


  .Lcol4 {
float:left;
     position: relative;
     width:16.5%;

 }



  .Lcol5 {
float:left;
     position: relative;
     width:16.5%;

 }


  .Lcol6 {
float:left;
     position: relative;
     width:
}

<div id="columns">
<span class="col1">
<?php
$i=1;
while ($i<$other) {
echo "text1";
    }
?>
</span>
<span class="col2">
<?php
$i=1;
while ($i<2) {
echo "text2";
    }
?>
</span>
<span class="col3">
<?php
$i=1;
while ($i<2) {
echo "text3";
    }
?>
</span>
<span class="col4">
<?php
$i=1;
while ($i<2) {
echo "text4";
    }
?>
</span>
<span class="col5">
<?php
$i=1;
while ($i<2) {
echo "text5";
    }
?>
</span>
<span class="col6">
<?php
$i=1;
while ($i<2) {
echo "text6";
    }
?>
</span>
</div>

<div id="header2">
header2
</div>`enter code here`
```

The problem is that "header2" is still printing in a column. Even if I remove a column one at a time the header is still printing in a column? WHY? Without the PHP code it works fine but I need the PHP to echo the data. Why would the PHP mess up the html here?

Comment: What do you mean by *"printing in a column"*?

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle File..

Comment: Should be `echo "text1";` or `echo $text1` everywhere you have used echo.

Comment: Please post any css, sounds like you have a float being applied.

Comment: Header 2 is still printing, because, it is static HTML text just written there

Comment: try to reduce your problem to a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)  That should make it a lot easier to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use css property "float" to do your columns ? if so you could try to put this between your "columns" div and your "header2" div :

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

But without css it's difficult to see your problem...

Comment: OK, so now I feel as stupid as I am!  <div style="clear:both"></div>  did the trick

Comment: moonyoh  Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: no prob, don't forget to check the right answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

Providing some CSS would be useful here.

My guess is that when not using the PHP there's no content, and the header is not showing in the columns, because they're not there. Otherwise, check your resulting html. This seems to be more of a CSS, or proper HTML structuring issue than PHP related.

Off the record:
Why you'd use a 'while' for the echo's remains a mystery to me.

Comment: added css . As I said this script is simular to what I have the WHILE loop is needed to echo the data in each column from database the actual script is very legnthy. after exiting the column DIV "HEADER" still prints in column 6. If I remove column 6 it prints in 5, etc. It is not breaking out of columns